# How to distinguish documentclass environment that is current in

Tags: beamer, document-classes, expl3, article

The environment is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
```

Or:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
```

Following is an accustomed command sequence, \pog, which is written with the two package commands, sparse and expl3, except the second line one that is merely for expressing question but not a affirmative command in term of certain package:

```
 If documentclass={Beamer}{% if
  }%if
  {%if
  }%if
```

The complete command: \pog

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\pog}{m o O{Detail} m m}{ %newCS
If documentclass={Beamer}{% if
\IfValueTF{#2}{ %if
    \tl_set:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {#4}
    \tl_case:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {%  case
        \c_enum_tl { %c_enum_tl
            \begin{frame}{#1}
             \begin{columns}
                \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
                    \begin{figure}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/#2}
                    \end{figure}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
                    \begin{block}{#3}
                        \begin{#4}
                            #5
                        \end{#4}
                    \end{block}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
         \end{frame}
        }%c_enum_tl

        \c_desc_tl { %desc_tl
                 \begin{frame}{#1}
                    \begin{columns}
                \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
                    \begin{figure}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/#2}
                    \end{figure}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{0.5\linewidth}
                    \begin{block}{#3}
                        \begin{#4}
                            #5
                        \end{#4}
                    \end{block}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
        \end{frame}
        }%desc_tl
    }%case
}%if
{%if
\tl_set:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {#4}      
\tl_case:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {%  case
        \c_enum_tl { %c_enum_tl
                   \begin{frame}{#1}
                        \begin{#4}
                            #5
                        \end{#4}
                    \end{frame}
        }%c_enum_tl

        \c_desc_tl { %desc_tl
               \begin{frame}{#1}                        
                    \begin{#4}
                            #5
                        \end{#4}
                     \end{frame}
        }%desc_tl
    }%case
}%if

}%if
{%if
    \tl_set:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {#4}
    \tl_case:Nn \l__hezilun_tmp_tl {%  case
        \c_enum_tl { %c_enum_tl
            \paragraph{#1}
                    \begin{figure}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/#2}
                    \end{figure}
                       \subpragraph{#3}
                        \begin{#4}
                            #5
                        \end{#4}
            }%c_enum_tl

        \c_desc_tl { %desc_tl
                \paragraph{#1}
                    \begin{figure}
                        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/#2}
                    \end{figure}
                       \subpragraph{#3}
                        \begin{#4}
                            #5
                        \end{#4}
        }%desc_tl
    }%case
{% if
}%newCS
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Please add a *full* minimal working example (all important definitions).

Comment: `\makeatletter\@ifclassloaded{foo}{yes}{no}\makeatother` outside of package files, otherwise omit the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's the version suggested in the linked question...

Comment: @TeXnician Exactly, the post is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @TeXnician: Didn't follow the link :-P

Comment: If you want to simultaneously produce a beamer and an article version of your content, you should look into `beamerarticle`.